caddy running on a local docker is getting the local IP instead of WAN IP when loading checkip.amazonaws.com
Those couple of services give you your current WAN IP:

I Can Haz => http://icanhazip.com/
AWS => http://checkip.amazonaws.com/

Loading them on the browser gives you your WAN IP like this:


This is the correct IP in both cases.
Now I want to play around with the caddy reverse proxy. To do so I run two instances with those two commands:
docker run -it --rm -p 7001:80 caddy caddy reverse-proxy --from :80 --to http://icanhazip.com:80 --change-host-header
docker run -it --rm -p 7002:80 caddy caddy reverse-proxy --from :80 --to http://checkip.amazonaws.com:80 --change-host-header

So it is supposed that all traffic to localhost:7001 should be proxied into http://icanhazip.com and all traffic to localhost:7002 to http://checkip.amazonaws.com
My surprise is this: While I Can Haz properly responds with my WAN IP, AWS responds with an internal IP in my docker network:


I see it's my network with docker network inspect bridge:

This is most probably a problem with my caddy configuration, because if I reach those ping-back servers with wget from inside the 2 instances, all them respond well.
The containers are: beautiful_diffie and exciting_northcutt and using any of those containers to reach any of the IP ping-back providers all work well:

Question
Why? What's going on? How can the external sever answer the internal IP instead of the public IP?

The problem here is that caddy is adding the X-Forwarded-For header in the forwarded request.
This means that both the IP from caddy and the initial IP are sent.
While I Can Haz responds with the IP making the request to them, AWS responds with the original IP sent on the header.
Unfortunately it seems that caddy does not allow to force drop the X-Forwarded-For header from the command line.
While this issue https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/issues/3976 suggests to set this in the config header_up -X-Forwarded-For (Note the '-' sign) it seems the command line does not still support it:

$ docker run -it --rm -p 7002:80 caddy caddy reverse-proxy --from :80 --to http://checkip.amazonaws.com:80 --change-host-header --header-up "-X-Forwarded-For"
Error: header-up 0: invalid format "-X-Forwarded-For" (expecting "Field: value")

PD: Edited as per Francis' comment to be more accurate answer.

This is false, the issue you linked literally shows header_up -X-Forwarded-For is how you remove the header from being passed upstream.

Humm... I'll modify my answer to be more acurate. Please reconsider the vote.
